# OctoberCMS Responsiv Uploader Plugin, files has null values

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems, octobercms, uploader

I use the uploader plugin to upload pdf files. I have followed the documentation implementing it on the components in the init function. this my following code

```
    public function init(){
    $tripFiles = $this->addComponent(
        'Responsiv\Uploader\Components\FileUploader',
        'tripFiles',
        [
            'fileTypes'             => '.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt, .pptx',
            'placeholderText'       => "Drag and drop file here or Browse File",
        ],
        ['deferredBinding'       => true]
    );
    $tripFiles->bindModel('files', ($this->property('tripId') ? Trip::find((int)$this->property('tripId')) : new Trip));
}


public function onSave(){
   $data = post();
    var_dump($data);
    $vacation = new Trip;
    $vacation->fill($data);
    $vacation->save(null, post('_session_key'));
}
```

but I found the output with null value on array of _uploader in files.

```
array:10 [▼
  "_handler" => "onCreateXXX"
  "_session_key" => "XXXXXXXXXX"
  "_token" => "XXXXXXXXXX"
  "name" => "XXXXX"
  "destination_name" => "XXXX"
  "purpose_id" => "1"
  "purpose" => ""
  "charge_code" => "XXXX"
  "city_id" => "1"
  "_uploader" => array:1 [▼
    "files" => ""
  ]
]
```

FrontEnd

```
{{ form_ajax('onSave')}}
   {% component 'tripFiles' %}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-90"> Create Trip </button>
{{ form_close() }}
```

so anyone can help me this problem ??

Comment: can you please share more info about how you are showing component in frontend side and where (code location) you are dumping array.

Comment: already posted my component in fronted

Comment: can you also share on which location you are trying to debug, means dump that data `array:10`

Comment: just var_dump(post()); in function

Comment: yes, but can you share where you are adding that :)

Comment: well, just added my function onSave

Answer (score 0):

Here problem is there are 2 models, and yes you wont be able to see file's data in `post` I guess.

1. which is used in `init` either new one or based on `tripId`
2. which is again new model in `onSave` anyhow not related to model which is binded to the widget in `init` method.

You need to make sure `same model` is used in `both case` so, may be create one variable which can hold model and use that in both scenario.

```php
public $vacationModel = null;

public function init() {
    $tripFiles = $this->addComponent(
        'Responsiv\Uploader\Components\FileUploader',
        'tripFiles',
        [
            'fileTypes'             => '.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt, .pptx',
            'placeholderText'       => "Drag and drop file here or Browse File",
        ],
        ['deferredBinding'       => true]
    );
    $this->vacationModel = $this->property('tripId') 
          ? Trip::find((int)$this->property('tripId')) 
          : new Trip;
    $tripFiles->bindModel('files', $this->vacationModel);

}

public function onSave() {
    $data = post();
    $this->vacationModel->fill($data);
    $this->vacationModel->save(null, post('_session_key'));   
}
```

> This should solve your issue.

if any doubts please comment.